# Facebook Graph API hashtag search with permanent token

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, hashtag

I have a working Angular application in which I included the option to retrieve hashtag media through Facebook's API. I have this functioning code:

```
login() {
    this.showSelect = true;
    window['FB'].login((response) => {

      if (response.authResponse) {
        window['FB'].api('/me', {
          fields: 'last_name, first_name, email'
        }, (userInfo) => {
          if (userInfo) {
            this.fbId = userInfo.id;

            window['FB'].api('/me/accounts', (res) => {
              if (res.data && res.data.length > 0) {
                this.NgZone.run(() => {
                  this.fbPages = res.data;
                  this.selectedPage = res.data[0];

                  if (this.selectedPage.access_token) {
                    this.retrievePermanentToken(window['FB'].getAccessToken());
                  }
                })
              }
            })
          }
        })
      } else {
        console.log('User login failed');
      }
    }, { scope: 'email, pages_show_list, instagram_basic, public_profile, pages_read_user_content, business_management, pages_read_engagement' })
  }
```

This is my login function, and it works as expected. However, I want to retrieve and store a permanent token so my users don't have to re-login. The problem with this comes in my `retrievePermanentToken` function.

```
retrievePermanentToken(token) {
    window['FB'].api(`/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=${environment.fbConfig.appId}&client_secret=${environment.fbConfig.secretKey}&fb_exchange_token=${token}`, (res) => {

      window['FB'].api(`/${this.fbId}/accounts?access_token=${res.access_token}`, (data) => {
        const index = data.data.findIndex(item => item.id === this.selectedPage.id);
        this.fbAuthToken = data.data[index].access_token;

        window['FB'].api(`/${this.selectedPage.id}?fields=instagram_business_account`, (data) => {
          if (data.instagram_business_account) {
            this.igId = data.instagram_business_account.id
          } else if (data.id) {
            this.igId = data.id
          }

          window['FB'].api(`/ig_hashtag_search?user_id=` + this.igId + '&q=bexfy&access_token=' + this.fbAuthToken, (res) => {
            console.log(res)
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

The problem is: if I use `this.fbAuthToken` which should be my permanent token, the hashtag search sends this error: `message: "The requested resource does not exist"` while, if I use the standard token it functions as I want it to.

I'm not exactly sure where I am failing at so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this all client-side code? Then you are doing things _fundamentally_ wrong already, by exposing your client secret in client-side code.

Comment: It is intended to eventually include part of the process server-side. But first, I have been asked to do it client-side, and it's not really my choice to make. Aside from vulnerabilities, which shouldn't impede it working, I have no idea where I am wrong in the code.

Comment: So what has your debugging resulted in so far? Did you make outputs of the token values you got, and checked them vie the debug tool?

Comment: FYI, you don’t need to loop through `user-id/accounts`, if you want to get the token for a specific page with a known ID, you can go via `page-id?fields=access_token` directly.

Comment: Whenever I try that `/ig_hashtag_search` query with the fbAuthToken I get:
`{
 "error": {
  "message": "The requested resource does not exist",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 24,
  "error_subcode": 2207024,
  "is_transient": false,
  "error_user_title": "No se encontr\u00f3 ning\u00fan hashtag coincidente",
  "error_user_msg": "No se puede ver el hashtag \"bexfy\" que el usuario solicit\u00f3 porque faltan permisos, no es v\u00e1lido o no existe.",
  "fbtrace_id": "AWYnZCZR58udU426IEkMqTH"
 }
}`